# MySQL Connection String Using FQDN

Tags: mysql, vb.net, fqdn

Is it possible to connect on MySQL server using FQDN?

e.g.

from

```
Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.90.99;Database=testdb;User ID=testadmin;Password=adminpass;")
```

to

```
Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=myserver.oldcompany.com;Database=testdb;User ID=testadmin;Password=adminpass;")
```

where the `myserver.oldcompany.com` is fqdn

If so, do we need any other configuration on server setup etc?

Answer (score 0):

of course. 
write in /etc/hosts file string:
myserver.oldcompany.com 192.168.90.99
check correctness with ping myserver.oldcompany.com
done.